# Xamarin iOS image change transition

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am developing an app with Xamarin.IOS and i am not using Xamarin.Forms.
I have a screen where i have set an Image View.
Now i would like to change between 2/3/4 images with a transition (fade, move in ... does not matter).
Is there a way i can do that?
Here is my code until now:

```
        imgView.AnimationImages = new UIImage[] {
            UIImage.FromBundle ("tmp_running.jpg")
            , UIImage.FromBundle ("tmp_cycling.jpg")

        } ;
        imgView.AnimationRepeatCount = 0;
        imgView.AnimationDuration = 3;
        imgView.StartAnimating ();
```

I have tried the approach:

```
        CATransition customTransition = new CATransition();
        customTransition.FadeInDuration = 3.0f;
        customTransition.FadeOutDuration = 3.0f;
        customTransition.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(
            CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseInEaseOut);
        customTransition.Type = CATransition.TransitionFade;

        and then : 
        imgView.Layer.AddAnimation(customTransition, null);
```

But nothing worked.

Do you know how to do this simple task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could do something like this:

```
    static int count = 0;
    UIImageView _imageView;

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        _imageView = new UIImageView (new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
        _imageView.Image = new UIImage ("1.png");
        Add (_imageView);

        animateImage ();
    }

    public void animateImage()
    {
        var animationImages = new List<UIImage> () {
            UIImage.FromFile ("1.png"),
            UIImage.FromFile ("2.png"),
            UIImage.FromFile ("3.png"),
            UIImage.FromFile ("4.png"),
            UIImage.FromFile ("5.png")};

        UIImage image = animationImages[count % animationImages.Count];

        UIView.Transition (_imageView, 3.0,
            UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
            () => {_imageView.Image = image;},
            () => { animateImage ();
                    count++; }
        );
    }
```

Comment: No worries glad to help!